# How to fix "invalid index to scalar variable" error, in case of reversed arrays

Tags: python, arrays, lambda, scipy

```
r = (b**2+z**2)**(1/2)
rho_0 = 0.17                  
r_0 = 1.12                    
d = 0.54      

def WS(A,r):

      rho = rho_0/(1+np.exp((r-R(A))/d))
      return rho
  
    def R(A): 
                     
      R = r_0*A**(1/3)-0.86*A**(-1/3)
      return R

    def collision(A_particle,B_particle,d):

        t = lambda r: WS(A_particle,r)*WS(B_particle,r)[::-1]
        T = scipy.integrate.quad(t,0,d)[0]
```

---

```
---> 21     t = lambda r: WS(A_particle,r)*WS(B_particle,r)[::-1]
     22     T = scipy.integrate.quad(t,0,d)[0]
     23     print('az ütközések száma: '+

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

If I don't use the reversed array it works fine.

I checked their type and lenght and they are the same, and I don't know how to fix this. Also tried to write a new function, which gives the reversed array back, but that didn't work either.

```
def WSrev(A,r):

    rho = rho_0/(1+np.exp((r-R(A))/d))
    return rho[::-1]
```

Comment: have you tried `rho.astype(int)[::-1]`

Comment: Without `A_particle` etc we can't recreate this.  I'd suggest changing the `t` lambda` to a regular `def` function, and adding a few diagnostic prints.  `r` for example will be a scalar, the integration variable.  I don't know what `WS(B_particle,r)` produces, but `t` should return a scalar, just one value.  You are doing a simple integration of a scalar function with `quad`.  I don't the see the point to trying to reverse  a 'scalar'.

Comment: to M Z: yes, it gives back the same error:(

Comment: to hpaulj: WS(B_particle,r) gives back an array, just like WS(A_particle,r). Thank you for the suggestion, I'll try it out